# How should I version control my bash profile?

Tags: version-control, git, bash

So I'm very comfortable with version control, and just thought to start tracking versions of my bash profile: `~/.bash_profile` with the added benefit of being able to share my various aliases and such on GitHub.

Assuming that my .bash_profile file needs to stay in my home directory(I can't wrap it in a directory to track it alone like a normal file), what would be the best way to go about this? I don't want to initialize a git repo in my home directory, and have to ignore every other file present.

So what might be a good solution?

I suppose I could just make a copy of it in a separate directory and update it / commit it from time to time, but I'm curious if there's a good way to version control a single file in a populated directory?

Comment: Symbolic links are your friends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Afaik, typically there're two ways of doing this: a) symbolic link b) syncing script. In both case, you have to create another repo (name it `dotfile` below) for `bash_profile` to be version controlled.

#### Use symbolic links

`bash_profile` gets moved to your version controlled dir(containing `.git`),  `$HOME/.bash_profile` is a soft link ⇢ `$HOME/dotfile/bash_profile`.

`$HOME/dotfile/bash_profile` is where your actual `bash_profile` resides, see [holman dotfile](https://github.com/holman/dotfiles) as an example.

#### Use syncing script

`bash_profile` stays in your `HOME` dir but it's only a copy of the 'latest' one . The latest `bash_profile` still lives in `$HOME/dotfile`.

Yep, it's a copy and paste approach, this is why you need some `syncing script`to save you from *DRY* work. see [mathiasbynens dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) as an good example. His `syncing script` https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/bootstrap.sh.

#### Furthermore

As you suspect:

> I'm curious if there's a good way to version control a single file in a populated directory

Version controlling a single file doesn't make much sense, copy & paste or just drop it into some cloud drives saves you much hassle.

The real point is that things don't get scaled this way, when the `dotfiles` in your `$HOME` grows, when you want to version control your favorite text editor's config(say `vimrc`), when you use `SSH` to work with multiple shell remotely, you might have `zshrc`, `bashrc`, `fishrc` etc.

This means in the long run you might want to version control all your `dotfile`s. [Github's dotfile](https://dotfiles.github.io/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Hadn't heard of symbolic links before! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer. Lots of other good ideas for putting this and other dotfiles in a repo can be found here: https://dotfiles.github.io/

Comment: @kevinmicke Glad it helps :)

Comment: "Version controlling a single file doesn't make much sense" Super disagree. I have so many random env vars accumulated over the years, I have to keep comments on them to tell what they are. I would have much preferred to just have it tracked in git, with commit messages to explain context.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to deport your specific configuration (as setting your own aliases or defining your own functions) to a different file than `.bash_profile`. This way, only your specific configuration will be versioned and you only have to source it from your `.bash_profile`.

#### Do it manually

Let's say this `.bash_profile` extension file is named `bash_profile_ext` and contained into the `/path/to/bash/profile/ext/` directory:

At the end of your `.bash_profile` file you will have:

```
source /path/to/bash/profile/ext/bash_profile_ext
```

And only your `/path/to/bash/profile/ext` directory will be versioned.

#### Do it using a third party app

Even simpler (I guess :-)), I'm developing [shprofile](https://github.com/abourdon/shprofile) that helps you to manage your shell profile, by only focusing on your specific profile configuration. shprofile allows you to define all your specific profile configuration into a single directory, which can then be versioned. Note you can also manage several profiles for the same user.

Again, no need to version all your `.bash_profile` configuration, but only your added values.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to initialize a git repo in my home directory, and have to ignore every other file present.

Why not? You want to track a file in your home directory, thus your home directory should be under version control, too.

That doesn't mean that your home directory needs to be a git repository. Let me explain:

git repositories consist of two parts: a working tree (unless it's a bare repository of course) and the `.git` "database" directory. Usually the later is just a (hidden) sub directory of the former, but that's not strictly necessary. git supports using a **detached working tree**. Thus you can keep your home directory under version control but don't need to have it contain a `.git` directory that could confuse tools (vim, emacs, ...) or git itself.

Setting up:

```
cd ~
mkdir .dotfiles
cd .dotfiles
git init .
```

Now there's a `~/.dotfiles/.git` directory. Use that but specify the home directory as working tree. This requires quite a long command line, thus an alias is a good idea:

```
alias dotfiles='git --git-dir ~/.dotfiles/.git --work-tree=$HOME'
```

To use it just use the above alias instead of `git`, e.g. `dotfiles status`.

Benefits:

- no other tools necessary, just git
- no symlink hell / out of sync situations possible
- git repositories in sub directories below home are not affected in any way

I got this from [this blog post](https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2015/06/22/keep-your-home-dir-in-git-with-a-detached-working-directory/)(which has some additional Infos) and am using it without any issues. I don't, but with a simple line `*` in `.gitignore` you can get rid of the possibly huge amount of untracked files and safeguard yourself a bit against adding files to the repository that aren't meant to be added.

Comment: Good point! Besides might need to re-define some existing git* alias I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For enterprise level IT configuration management, many are using Puppet. I recommend Puppet to clients as a cost containment and reliability measure. Here in the lab, we keep it simple.

Our main repository contains files needed to completely rebuild a crashed system or build a new user account, and the version control has been useful on several occasions.  Git is fine with files and directories that start with a period as long as git is not configured to ignore them.

These are repository paths for system and application installation and configuration.

> knowledge.resources/install.linux/std.fedora.dnf.sh (dnf installations)
>   knowledge.resources/install.linux/font.install.info.te (font installation)
>   knowledge.resources/install.linux/std.fedora.te (other install and config)

These are general user configuration files.

> startup/linux.basic.user/.bash_profile
>   startup/linux.basic.user/.bashrc
>   startup/linux.basic.user/.vimrc
>   startup/linux.basic.user/.gitmessage
>   startup/linux.basic.user/.gitconfig
>   startup/linux.basic.user/use.ls.al.to.see.dot.files.here

These are for remote accounts on servers.

> startup/linux.remote/.bash_profile
>   startup/linux.remote/.bashrc
>   startup/linux.remote/.vimrc
>   startup/linux.remote/.gitmessage
>   startup/linux.remote/.gitconfig
>   startup/linux.remote/use.ls.al.to.see.dot.files.here

These are for the root account.

> startup/linux.root/.bash_profile
>   startup/linux.root/.bashrc
>   startup/linux.root/.vimrc
>   startup/linux.root/use.ls.al.to.see.dot.files.here

I use zero-size files called use.ls.al.to.see.dot.files.here to remind me that the directory only LOOKS empty.

Answer (score -1):

One more idea: You can add your profile to a GitHub Gist and use a CLI tool (like [this one](https://github.com/defunkt/gist)) to update it.